# Serialize SOAP Header as Document Style XML

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, mono

I have a proxy to a SOAP web service that requires a session object in the SOAP header. The web service is unable to read the session information from the header when it is in the form using a reference:

```
 <SessionInfo href="#id1"/>

 <SessionInfo id="id1"> 
     <UID>1</UID> 
 </SessionInfo>
```

The service I am using requires a RPC style body. However, in mono the header is also encoded as RPC style. The service requires a Document style header. Is it possible to force the header to be encoded as Document style while the body is encoded as RPC style? The proxy created in Visual Studio does this correct, while the proxy created with Mono does not.

Comment: How are you hosting this? Where does the code for this live? Typically, this is a matter of disabling RPC-XML.

Comment: The proxy is created using the wsdl proxy generator from mono.